# Google Translator causes navigation links to fail

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, google-translate

We have added the google translator to our sharepoint site. But it is causing our navigation to fail. After the conversion the translator is adding two html  tags to each of the elements.

**Before Translation:**

```
<span class="menu-item-text">Who We Are</span>
```

**After Translation:**

`<span class="menu-item-text"><font><font class="">हम कौन हैं</font></font></span>`

**Code in the master page for google Translation:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE }, 'google_translate_element');}
    //]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">//<![CDATA[ //]]>
</script>
```

I have manually removed those  tags and that made the navigation to work again. Do you have any workaround for this?
is it possible to remove those tags after the translation happens through javascript?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the below script to fix this issue which will not override any Google translator added features.
It will select the elements based on the class and set the link of all the children elements to the parent link "href" value,

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".menu-item-text").on("click", function (event) {
    location.href = $(this).parent().parent().attr("href");
});
});
```